# Unable to make a field searchable in Solr

Tags: php, solr

I am having difficulties performing a search using Solr on certain fields. I am using Solarium as the "bridge" between the PHP code and the Apache Solr Search Server.

When I perform a search on "product_name" it returns successfully, however if I search on style_colour or style_number it does not. I have made both fields "indexed" in the schema, which, AFAIK, makes them searchable.

Can anyone advise what i'm doing wrong here?

Schema:

```
<field name="product_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="style_colour" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="style_number" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Result from a Solr Admin "get me everything" query:

```
<result name="response" numFound="1071" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="product_name">Farls</str>
    <str name="style_colour">01701901701931</str>
    <str name="style_number">017019</str>
  </doc>
  ...
```

Comment: how do you query on these fields ? whats your default search field ?

Comment: @Jayendra How can I check what my default search field is?

Comment: schema.xml file should mention the defaultsearchfield, which is usually text field. Also are you querying over specific fields ? any specific request handler in solrconfig.xml ? additional details would help to provide a suitable answer.

Comment: Were the style_* fields originally not indexed (stored="false")? If so, you will need to reindex the data to have the updated stored value take effect.

Comment: @Jayendra The following are taken from the two files in question here: schema.xml default search field section:

`<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>`

solrconfig.xml request handler section:

`<requestHandler name="search" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <int name="rows">10</int>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>`

Comment: @PaigeCook The style* fields were both set as indexed="true" in schema.xml, essentially I have not changed the schema I just want the ability to search on another field.

Comment: updated the answer. You can try and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following in your schema -

```
<copyField source="product_name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="style_colour" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="style_number" dest="text"/>
```

Also, make sure the field text is defined in your schema.
Would need to re-index your data again.
Using the standard request handler, your query would search the three fields.

Comment: I tracked down and resolved this issue, as I am using Solarium I had to go deeper into this code and found that the `Solarium_Client_Request_Select` class will take in the query fields that I give it: `$this->addParam('qf', $component->getQueryFields());`. This is found withing the addDisMax method (i'm actually using eDisMax) Previously, I have found that I was _not_ passing through style_number so that mad it unsearchable. I have now added this in and it has now become searchable. Thanks very much for your help.